# Socket issue between workstations

Tags: delphi, tclientsocket

Recently, i encounter an issue on socket between different workstations. I'm using Delphi TClientSocket to connect a server and received data from it. And per my testing, i found the TClientSocket received data unstable in different workstations.

The server's reside in a Windows XP (SP2), and keep broadcasting msg in 10000kbps. There are another two more Windows XP (SP2) running the same client app receiving data from the server. But the result's so different that one client keep receiving data in 10000kbps, while the other one only 300kbps.

Is there possible that these two client app testing Windows XP (SP2) workstations have something in different will cause this result? Something like the registry value, or else?

Please help, thank you.

Comment: Since you're *broadcasting* what seems to be a large amount of data, did you try swapping the network connections between the two client computers to make sure it's not something related to the networking hardware between the server and client? Did you try disabling antivirus software and the firewall on the PC that's not receiving as much as you expect?

Comment: @Cosmin, actually these two client computers reside in the same network segmentation, and surely both of them firewall's disabled. But i need to confirm whether or not both of them disabled the antivirus software, since at lease there's one running a Symentec antivirus

Comment: @Cusmin, finally checked the testing environment, both the client computers run the antivirus software Synmantec, and the firewall's shutdown. And they're in the same network segmentation, since i'm testing them in an intranet. Is it possible any other reason?

Answer (score 0):

IMHO this is related to your network. To control the speed into a network, you must control devices which sent the data (routers, modems,hubs or other network devices). All the stations have the same OS, antivirus (this can 'slow' the data receiving by it's scanning method), and applications? Have you other network 'consuming resources' elements on the 'slow' computer?

PS: I believe is more reliable to use Indy suite http://www.indyproject.org/index.en.aspx instead of using TClientSocket.

best regards,
Radu

Comment: thanks for your comment. And i've checked the network, and both of them in the same network segmentation, and the ping delay time is less than 1ms.